# How do I tell an aside tag which side to go on?

Tags: html

I have an html5 aside tag in a page I'm making. I can't find a way of telling it which side of the main article to be on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do it through CSS, e.g. if you want your `aside` tags to be on the left you would do

```
aside { float:left; }
```

Comment: so it doesn't give an automatic sidebar?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Like ondrej mentioned, it is a semantic enhancement. That means tags like this give your content a more meaningful context for various apps that may process your page.

Answer (score 7):

`<aside>` is just a semantic enhancement of general `<div>` container - it does not carry any presentational (graphic) info with itself.

You have to style it with CSS in order to put it to some specific place in your layout. For example, with `float: left` property.

Comment: So it doesn' automatically give any advantages over a div?

Answer (score -1):

aside should not be used as a sidebar at all.  Like the other answers say, it's a semantic enhancement that is similarly named but unrelated to a sidebar/sidenav.

For a sidebar, using div or section or nav (if it's a navigation sidebar) would be more correct.

Think of the aside element as your page talking directly to the viewer about content in the same parent element.  Use it to enhance or showcase content in that parent.  Like a shakespeare character talking to the audience.  Pullquotes and piecharts in print magazines are good examples of asides.

For a sidebar, however, use section or nav and style it with css, floating it to one side or the other.

Comment: The W3C states "The element can also be used for **typographical effects like pull quotes or sidebars,** for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page." See, for example, [Using HTML5 aside element](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_aside_element)